# Add security constraint on tomcat AWS elastic beansatlk enviornment

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am trying to add a security constraint on the tomcat server side to implement a username and password for the whole application. So every time I call a url, the security constraint kicks in to authenticate before accessing. We don't want information out in the public like it currently is.

So here's what I have so far in my WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="tomcat-demo" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>


</web-app>
```

Now, from my understanding I need to create a tomcat-users.xml. So I did that too. Here's what that code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat" />
  <role rolename="role1" />

  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat" />
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1" />
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Now here's where I am super confused. Where the heck do I put tomcat-users.xml file? Reading on aws documentation, I would need to "Extend extend Elastic Beanstalk's default Apache configuration." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html#java-tomcat-proxy-apache

To be honest I have no idea how to exactly achieve what the AWS document is asking. So AWS doc says to create directory like this:

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- .ebextensions
|   `-- httpd
|       `-- conf.d
|           `-- myconf.conf
`-- index.jsp
```

Eclipse neon, nor Mac OSX will let me create a directory with a dot in it. So could someone help clarify where exactly tomcat-users.xml file should live so it can be seen and utilized correctly by web.xml file? Or maybe to better clarify my question is my thinking right? Should I be looking into putting the tomcat-users.xml into the .ebextensions directory like AWS suggests?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!